# GKE Ingress TLS vs jupyter TLS but not both?

Tags: ssl, https, jupyter, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I'm setting up a `jupyter-lab` container in a kubernetes cluster and want to enable TLS. I have successfully done this in 2 ways:

1. Include the certificate and key files inside the container and enable TLS when running the jupyter command. Add a `LoadBalancer` `Service` to expose the container.

```
#Dockerfile
...

CMD jupyter-lab --no-browser --allow-root --ip 0.0.0.0 --port=443 --certfile=<crt path> --keyfile=<key path>
```

```yaml
#yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: <service-name>
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: <app-name>
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 443
    targetPort: 443
```

2. Run jupyter with no TLS. Add certificate and key in base64 to a Secret. Add NodePort, Ingress and BackendConfig yamls.

```
#Dockerfile
...

CMD jupyter-lab --no-browser --allow-root --ip 0.0.0.0 --port=443
```

```yaml
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: http-hc-config
spec:
  healthCheck:
    checkIntervalSec: 300
    timeoutSec: 10
    healthyThreshold: 2
    unhealthyThreshold: 5
    type: HTTP
    requestPath: /login
    port: 443
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: <service-name>
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"ports": {"443":"http-hc-config"}}'
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: <app-name>
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 443
    targetPort: 443
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: <ingress-name>
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: <secret-name>
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: <service-name>
      port:
        number: 443
---
apiVersion: v1
data:
  tls-crt: <base64 crt>
  tls-key: <base64 key>
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: <secret-name>
type: kubernetes.io/tls
```

However, when I try to combine both (follow steps in 2, but also enable tls in jupyter-lab), I get `502` errors. Why is this?

Also, which setup is better?

Comment: In  terms of which setup is better, it really depends on your requirements.  If you need to terminate TLS all the way to the backend, then either 1 or the combined approach make sense.  Many people choose to solely terminate TLS at the load balancer, so 2 is a fairly common approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you want TLS between the HTTP(S) LB created by Ingress, you'll need to modify your BackendConfig to specify HTTPS for the healthcheck:

```
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: http-hc-config
spec:
  healthCheck:
    checkIntervalSec: 300
    timeoutSec: 10
    healthyThreshold: 2
    unhealthyThreshold: 5
    type: HTTPS
    requestPath: /login
    port: 443
```